# MVC, views knowing about model

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller

This may be a dumb question, but in MVC the view doesn't know about the model right.  I've looked at some examples for table view cells, and the table view cell has a property of the model object.  It then uses that model's property to fill in the label, or the image for the cell.

Or in another case, if I have a UIView to draw something dynamically based on the model, it seems like it would be the easiest to have a property on the UIView so the UIView can access that model's data in order to draw it dynamically.  So I could do something like this:

```
myView.object = newObject;
[myView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Is this wrong for MVC?  If so, what are the better ways to do these two things?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or in another case, if I have a UIView to draw something dynamically
>   based on the model, it seems like it would be the easiest to have a
>   property on the UIView so the UIView can access that model's data in
>   order to draw it dynamically.

So what would you have the view say to the model in order to get the right information? It has to know something about the model in order to ask the right question, right? Alternately, you could define a protocol like `UITableViewDataSource` and send generic messages like `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, and then implement that protocol in your model. That avoids the need for the view to know anything specific about the model, but it means instead that the model now has to know about the view -- it has to know something about what's supposed to be displayed in the view so that it can pass back the right data. Whichever way you go, you introduce a dependency between the model and the view, and that means that when you make a change in one you'll have to make a change in the other.

Avoiding those kinds of dependencies is exactly the point of the MVC architecture. The controller knows about both model and view, which allows the model and view to exist independent of each other.

It might sometimes make sense to have some objects that both model and view know about. If you're writing an address book, it might make sense to have a ContactView that knows how to display a Contact, and a model that stores Contact objects. That seems much more sensible than having a view that's completely stupid about what it's displaying, and it lets you pass around Contact objects instead of great long lists of name, address, phone, fax, email, etc. You could say that a Contact is a model object, and all the above applies: you'll be introducing a dependency between ContactView and Contact. But usually when we talk about "the model", we mean the whole graph of objects that the program uses to store its data, and the benefit of MVC is to separate the way you manage all those objects from the way you present the data that they contain.

Answer (score 4):

There are different variants of the MVC model - the Apple documentation on it for Cocoa is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH14-SW9.

The main thing I take from this is that **Views should not be directly linked to the Model.** See this diagram:

[image: Apple diagram of Cocoa MVC pattern]

You mention `UITableViewCells` as often having a property of the **Model** object - I would suggest this is wrong.  The pattern should be as follows:

- The **Model** handles all of the actual data storage and management
- The **View** knows the **type** of data that is being displayed, but not the data itself.
- The **Controller** (UITableViewController) is the 'glue' that takes data from the Model and sets up the View

**How does this work in practice?**

Excuse some mistakes in the following psuedo-code as I just typed it directly in, I haven't tested any of it, but hopefully it shows the point.

So you have a `UITableViewCell` sub-class which looks like this:

```
@interface PhoneEntryTableViewCell {

@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *personName;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UILabel *phoneNumber;

}
```

The **Model** looks like this:

```
@interface PhoneModel {

@property (strong) NSMutableArray *listOfPeople;

}
```

And the `UITableViewController` implements the standard `UITableViewDelegate`/`UITableViewDataSource` methods, for example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  Person *person = [myModel personForIndex:indexPath.row];

  PhoneEntryTableViewCell *cell = [self dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PhoneCell"];
  cell.personName.text = [person name];
  cell.phoneNumber.text = [person phoneNumber];

  return cell;
}
```

So in summary, the **View** does not have any idea of the actual data - it just knows it has to display a person's name and phone number.  It doesn't know what the back-end storage is - it could be Core Data, a file, a downloaded and parsed JSON, etc.  It doesn't know anything about the **Model** - for example, maybe it stores other data about the Person, maybe the phone number is actually stored in a different model to the name.  The **Controller** handles all of this work.

**Why do it this way?**

So you roll out the above application and then discover your **Model** is horribly slow - you can swap it out for a completely different model without touching the **View**.  Maybe you can have another developer or designer create the **View** - all they need to know is that it has to display two bits of text. Basically it allows your code to be clean, clearly partitioned, easily extensible, and easier to refactor.

Now, as soon as you do something like this in your `UITableViewCell` View, all of this goes away:

```
@property (strong) Person *person;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: There is no "the MVC model". It is outlined in different ways with subtile, but important differences.

If a component in the view needs to get information it can get this in two ways: Asking for it (polling), or being notified about it (pushing). Notification should be the cleaner approach in most cases, as the view really doesn't know anything about the model, it just works as [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

However, GUI components tend to need "model objects" that hold the data and can be asked for it, like in your example. Altough they're often named after the model, architecturally they don't need to belong to it. And in my opinion they shouldn't, as the model's interfaces then are built after the needs of predefined GUI components and the whole sense of MVC is gone. If you want a clear separation between model and view you should try something like this:

```
-----------------       -----------------       --------------      ---------
| GUI Component | --->  | "Model Class" | <-->  | Controller | ---> | Model |
-----------------       -----------------       --------------      ---------
```

So the "Model Class" object that is expected by the GUI component is nothing but an adapter for the controller. In this relation between GUI and Controller you can now implement whatever strategy you like - poll or push (the reason for the two-sided arrow).